# Rewrite left outer join involving multiple tables from Informix to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, informix, outer-join

How do I write an Oracle query which is equivalent to the following Informix query?

```
select tab1.a,tab2.b,tab3.c,tab4.d 
  from table1 tab1,
       table2 tab2 OUTER (table3 tab3,table4 tab4,table5 tab5) 
 where tab3.xya = tab4.xya 
   AND tab4.ss = tab1.ss 
   AND tab3.dd = tab5.dd 
   AND tab1.fg = tab2.fg 
   AND tab4.kk = tab5.kk 
   AND tab3.desc = "XYZ"
```

I tried:

```
select tab1.a,tab2.b,tab3.c,tab4.d 
  from table1 tab1,
       table2 tab2 LEFT OUTER JOIN (table3 tab3,table4 tab4,table5 tab5) 
 where tab3.xya = tab4.xya 
   AND tab4.ss = tab1.ss 
   AND tab3.dd = tab5.dd 
   AND tab1.fg = tab2.fg 
   AND tab4.kk = tab5.kk 
   AND tab3.desc = "XYZ"
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Which version of Oracle? The answer would be different for 8i or earlier.

Comment: Oracle 8i is like 100 years old. But still, doesn't it support joins?

Comment: @GolezTroi - ANSI style outer joins are only supported in Oracle 9i or later.  Prior to that Oracle only had its own bespoke syntax.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Write one table per join, like this:

```
select tab1.a,tab2.b,tab3.c,tab4.d 
from 
  table1 tab1
  inner join table2 tab2 on tab2.fg = tab1.fg
  left join table3 tab3 on tab3.xxx = tab1.xxx and tab3.desc = "XYZ"
  left join table4 tab4 on tab4.xya = tab3.xya and tab4.ss = tab3.ss
  left join table5 tab5 on tab5.dd = tab3.dd and tab5.kk = tab4.kk
```

<strike>Note that while my query contains actual left join, your query apparently doesn't. 
Since the conditions are in the where, your query should behave like inner joins. (Although I admit I don't know Informix, so maybe I'm wrong there).</strike>

[The specfific Informix extension used in the question works a bit differently](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1035.htm) with regards to left joins. Apart from the exact syntax of the join itself, this is mainly in the fact that in Informix, you can specify a list of outer joined tables. These will be left outer joined, and the join conditions can be put in the where clause. Note that this is a specific extension to SQL. Informix also supports 'normal' left joins, but you can't combine the two in one query, it seems.

In Oracle this extension doesn't exist, and you can't put outer join conditions in the where clause, since the conditions will be executed regardless.

So look what happens when you move conditions to the where clause:

```
select tab1.a,tab2.b,tab3.c,tab4.d 
from 
  table1 tab1
  inner join table2 tab2 on tab2.fg = tab1.fg
  left join table3 tab3 on tab3.xxx = tab1.xxx
  left join table4 tab4 on tab4.xya = tab3.xya
  left join table5 tab5 on tab5.dd = tab3.dd and tab5.kk = tab4.kk
where
  tab3.desc = "XYZ" and
  tab4.ss = tab3.ss
```

Now, only rows will be returned for which those two conditions are true. They cannot be true when no row is found, so if there is no matching row in table3 and/or table4, or if `ss` is null in either of the two, one of these conditions is going to return false, and no row is returned. This effectively changed your outer join to an inner join, and as such changes the behavior significantly.

PS: `left join` and `left outer join` are the same. It means that you optionally join the second table to the first (the left one). Rows are returned if there is only data in the 'left' part of the join. In Oracle you can also `right [outer] join` to make not the left, but the right table the leading table. And there is and even `full [outer] join` to return a row if there is data in either table.

Comment: Thankyou. Your answer gave me an idea how to solve my actual problem

Comment: The `OUTER(...)` clause turns the join into a left outer join. (That Informix syntax doesn't support any other sort of outer join. Later versions of Informix, like later versions of Oracle, support ANSI joins.)

Comment: Oracle does support LEFT, RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOIN. There's no such thing as a LEFT INNER JOIN or a LEFT CROSS JOIN. Therefore LEFT JOIN is just short for LEFT OUTER JOIN. The 'OUTER' keyword is optional, while the LEFT, RIGHT and FULL keywords are mandatory.

Comment: Your 1st left join can just be inner because the where eliminates any null-extended rows. But since you are just guessing at the conditions & join order, probably you would better just move the where test to the left join's on.

Comment: @philipxy Good point, even though the answer is 8 years old ;-) So, 8 years too late, I decided to look up (and link) this Informix syntax, and it turns out that outer join conditions should indeed be in the where clause in Informix. So I have now moved the condition to the join, to match what was asked. I have also added a second snippet to explain the difference between the databases a bit better, since in Oracle you indeed shouldn't put left join conditions in the where clause. Thanks for the push!

Answer (score 11):

I'm guessing that you want something like

```
SELECT tab1.a, tab2.b, tab3.c, tab4.d
  FROM table1 tab1 
       JOIN table2 tab2 ON (tab1.fg = tab2.fg)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 tab4 ON (tab1.ss = tab4.ss)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 tab3 ON (tab4.xya = tab3.xya and tab3.desc = 'XYZ')
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 tab5 on (tab4.kk = tab5.kk AND
                                       tab3.dd = tab5.dd)
```